# how to select the specific string from 'ls' command console output?

Tags: command-line, grep, ls

I am newbie on linux os. My target is selecting files which have the specific string values in filenames on console mode

This is my sample filename,

```
filename : apnic-2016-02-01
```

condition : The first letter of filename should not start with 'b' and the day value (01) should be odd value

Below is my command using pipe and grep command.

```
ls -al | grep -v [b]   --> choosing the filenames which dose not start with 'b' and working successfully
```

but I am stuck with selecting odd value in the filename. I wonder how to choose the odd day value on filename.

Any reply will be welcomed.

Comment: The format is year, month, and day?  As far as I know, I don't think there's a way to say "odd".  You might have to `grep` out even values instead.  They would end in 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.  So, `| grep -v "2$" | grep -v "4$" ...` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ls -d [!b]*[13579]
```

This command will select all files whose name doesn't start with 'b' and ends with a odd number.